# odoo 10: extending form view tree of related records (inventory.stock.line)

Tags: forms, view, odoo-10, extending

I need to extend a form (stock.view_inventory_form) in Odoo 10. The form has a sub-tree populated with related records from another model. Here's the part of the original form that I want to change:

```xml
 <field name="line_ids" string="Inventory Details" context="{'default_location_id': location_id,  'default_product_id': product_id, 'default_prod_lot_id': lot_id, 'default_package_id': package_id, 'default_partner_id': partner_id}" mode="tree,kanban">
  <tree string="Inventory Details" editable="bottom" decoration-info="product_qty != theoretical_qty" decoration-danger="theoretical_qty &lt; 0">
    <field name="product_id" domain="[('type','=','product')]"/>
    <field name="product_uom_id" string="UoM" groups="product.group_uom"/>
    <field name="location_id" domain="[('id', 'child_of', parent.location_id)]" groups="stock.group_stock_multi_locations"/>
    <field name="prod_lot_id" domain="[('product_id', '=', product_id)]" context="{'default_product_id': product_id}" groups="stock.group_production_lot"/>
    <field name="package_id" domain="['|', ('location_id','=', False), ('location_id', '=', location_id)]" groups="stock.group_tracking_lot"/>
    <field name="partner_id" groups="stock.group_tracking_owner"/>
    <field name="theoretical_qty" readonly="1"/>
    <field name="product_qty" string="Real Quantity"/>
    <field name="state" invisible="True"/>
  </tree>
</field>
```

Where line_ids is a field from a related model (stock.inventory.line). So I extended the model with the following:

```py
class stock_inventory_line(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'stock.inventory.line'

  x_container_details  = fields.Char('Container details')
  x_wagon_no  = fields.Char('Wagon No')
  x_seal_no  = fields.Char('Seal No')
  x_invoice_no  = fields.Integer('Invoice No')
  x_net_weight  = fields.Integer('Net weight')
  x_gross_weight  = fields.Integer('Gross Weight')
```

Then I tried to extend the form with the following code:

```xml
<record id="view_form_todo_task_inherited"  model="ir.ui.view"> 
    <field name="name">Test</field> 
    <field name="model">stock.inventory</field> 
    <field name="inherit_id"  ref="stock.view_inventory_form"/> 
    <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
        <field name="line_ids">
         <field name="x_container_details"/>
         <field name="x_wagon_no"/>
       </field>        
    </field> 
  </record>
```

Odoo is not returning any error, but my fields are not showed in the (sub) tree of the form.. what am I doing wrong? 
Thanks to anyone that can help with this!

Answer (score 2):

This is not the right way to extend a view, you should take a look [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#reference-views-inheritance).

You need to specify the position were you want to add or replace fields, this is an example to insert fields at the end of the list:

```xml
<record id="view_form_todo_task_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">Test</field>
<field name="model">stock.inventory</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_inventory_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <!-- to insert your fields at the end of the list -->
    <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='state']" position="after" >
        <field name="x_container_details"/>
        <field name="x_wagon_no"/>
    </xpath>
</field>
```

I hope this can be helpfull for you.

Comment: Thanks Juan Salcedo! It works.
I previously extended non-related fields the way I did in my example without xpath, so I assumed there was a way to do it without xpath.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, and YES, you could not use 'xpath' but you should indicate the position too, <field name="state" position="after">, but I think use 'xpath' it's more intuitive to use than 'field', and for your case if there is more that one 'state' definition, you can get troubles to find wich field(state) you want to use, that is why I specified '//tree/field' path.